# How to set an image as iframe borders in HTML?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to set a rounded corner image as Iframe borders using css.

Here is my iframe.css

```
iframe { border-image-source: url(pipe.jpg);
width:500px;
height:300px;
 }
```

iframe.html

```
 <iframe src="my_pics.html">
</iframe>
```

Everything is working fine, but Iframe is showing black borders instead of  image borders.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a border style before applying the border-image-source. Otherwise its displaying the image with zero width.

```
iframe { 
    border:10px solid transparent;
    border-image-source: url(pipe.jpg);
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
}
```

You may also want to set border-image-slice. This divides up the image to create a border. *The image is always sliced into nine sections: four corners, four edges and the middle.* -[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image-source.asp)

thus

```
iframe { 
    border:10px solid transparent;
    border-image-source: url(pipe.jpg);
    border-image-slice: 10;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Your border image slice value can be anything greater than 0 however i reckon for best results it should be the image width divided by 3.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/shootermatic/r6kLd4j4/)